# HD recognised by BIOS but not Windows

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, hardware-failure

I accidently dropped a hard drive a while back. It worked afterwards but now it seems something is wrong. I'm unsure if the drop has killed it or not.

The BIOS recognises it, but Windows 7 doesn't show it in My Computer. Any ideas how I could try get Windows to recognise it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone to **'Computer Management'** via right click on 'Computer' and select 'Manager' (or simply type 'Computer Management' in the start menu) and looked at **Storage > Disk Management**?

There you can initialize the disk, it if it has lost data / not formatted.

If it does not show up in Disk Management, you have a more serious problem, that may be sovled by things like a [chkdsk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHKDSK)

Or more advanced data recover tools like [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) (or many other popular ones).

Comment: I would note that if it does show up in Disk Management, but he lost the partition anyway, that the disk is not to be trusted, and should be replaced anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Check Device Manager first to see if it appears there. If not, the drive is probably too damaged to function at all. Hopefully, you had any data backed up.

But if it does appear there, try Disk Management (Run: diskmgmt.msc, or Admin Tools in Control Panel) to see what state it says the drive is in.

Usually a drop does its damage immediately, but you may have an exception. They are delicate.

**DO NOT USE CHKDSK** as you were advised if there is data to be recovered. Chkdsk is a great tool, but if the drive is damaged and chkdsk gets incorrect data from the partition table, it can scramble files so that CSI couldn't get them back even on TV. Attempt file recovery first.

(FYI: Chkdsk cannot be used on a drive that does not appear normal in Disk Management and is formatted. Chkdsk only repairs the file system and nothing else.)

> The hard drive in your computer is in one of two states right now. It's 
>   either going to fail or it already failed. Hard drives are inherently 
>   fragile things with no built in redundancy.
>                               -Chris Pirillo